# Method that contains parameter with generic Map.Entry

Tags: java, generics, java-8, generic-collections

I have 2 classes with very similar methods

Class A:

```
String getString(Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> headers) {
    return headers.stream().map(h -> String.join(": ", h.getKey(), h.getValue().stream().
            collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))).collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
}
```

Class B

```
String getString(Set<Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>>> headers) {
    return headers.stream().map(h -> String.join(": ", h.getKey(), h.getValue().stream().
            collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))).collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
}
```

The only difference in method argument generic type:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> headers
Set<Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>>> headers
```

I do not wont code duplication. And looking for way haw I can refactor this two method in one.

I was trying write code like with different combination of Generic wildcards (? super or ? extends). But failed with it. For examle:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, ? extends Collection<String>>>
```

Could you pleas support with idea how I can refactor this generic.
Thanks

Comment: I took your first method and reworked the method signature to: `    String getString(Set<Map.Entry<String, ? extends Collection<String>>> headers) {
` ... and that compiles nicely. So: unable to reproduce!

Comment: In that sense: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks! You see, *but failed with it* is not a problem description we could help with. What is the problem? Error message?

Answer (score 8):

You have to define a generic type T

```
public <T extends Collection<String>> String getString(Set<Map.Entry<String, T>> headers) {
    return headers.stream().map(h -> String.join(": ", h.getKey(), h.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))).collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
}
```

Comment: You don’t have to. Using `Set<Map.Entry<String, ? extends Collection<String>>>`, like the OP described, works smoothly.